# Getting all 42 days that appear on a calendar month in a single array using moment.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I am creating a calendar with JavaScript and Moment.js and would like to know how to create an array that contains all 42 days (dates) that should be displayed for the selected month.

I am using the moment getDaysInMonth() function to help me get the days in the currently selected month then looping through them pushing all of the dates to an array.

I am struggling filling in the final days of the previous month and the first few days of the next month (that you would typically see greyed out in a calendar).

Here is an example showing Week 1 and Week 6 in the array. The dots show the rest of the dates in between that can be assumed:

```
[new Date("2020-07-26"), new Date("2020-07-27"), new Date("2020-07-28"), new Date("2020-07-29"), new Date("2020-07-30"), new Date("2020-07-31"), new Date("2020-07-01"),................................................... new Date("2020-08-30"), new Date("2020-08-31"), new Date("2020-09-01"), new Date("2020-09-02"), new Date("2020-09-03"), new Date("2020-09-04"), new Date("2020-09-05")],
```

Comment: The week starts on Sunday, so check the day of the week for the 1st and back up the difference into the previous month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moment has functions for getting the start and end of certain periods, including month and week. You can use those to get the start of the month, and the start of the week the start of the month is in. Then do the same for the ends. Then just iterate over days between them, adding as you go.

```js
function getDaysForCalendarMonth(date) {
  var firstDayOfMonth = moment(date).startOf('month');
  var firstDayOfCal = firstDayOfMonth.clone().startOf('week');
  var lastDayOfMonth = firstDayOfMonth.clone().endOf('month');
  var lastDayOfCal = lastDayOfMonth.clone().endOf('week');
  var temp = firstDayOfCal.clone();
  var days = [temp.toDate()];
  while (temp.isBefore(lastDayOfCal) && days.length < 42) {
    temp.add(1, 'day');
    days.push(temp.toDate());
  }
  while (days.length < 42) {
    temp.add(1, 'day');
    days.push(temp.toDate());
  }
  return days;
}
console.log(getDaysForCalendarMonth(new Date(2020, 2, 1)));
console.log(getDaysForCalendarMonth(new Date(2020, 3, 1)));
console.log(getDaysForCalendarMonth(new Date()));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I ended up coming up with my own solution but it wasn't as clean as this one because I didn't utilize startOf week and endOf week. Any chance you can give me an idea of how you would now take this array of 42 dates and break it into an array of 6 week objects so it is easy to loop through and display on the UI in a table? For example weeks: [{week: 1, dates: [], {week: 2, dates: []}, etc....}]. Basically every 7 days I would want to break it into a new week object.

Comment: There's a number of ways of doing that. The term usually used is "chunking" the array. I always end up at [Split array into chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8495687/215552).

Comment: Got it I will look into it. Thank you! One final thing:  I noticed if I pass in new Date(2020,8,1) to your function it is incorrect, but new Date() works. Any idea why?

Comment: Months in JavaScript are 0 based, so today's month is 7.

Comment: Uggh, my brain is friend right now. I really appreciate all of the help. Thank you again! I am just trying to challenge myself to build a calendar widget.

Comment: No problem. I've built a couple in my career, and I'll give you some free advice: stick with the standard American/Gregorian calendar. There are some really challenging calendars out there! :)

Comment: @HereticMonkey How to do the same thing if there was no moment js? I wana build a custom calendar for my country which has a different calendar, I can only have start date of a month 1(january) and the total days of every month...

Answer (score 2):

You could consider this solution (long but works)

- get dates for current month: iterate through that month's date

  ```js
  iteratedDate = startOfMonth.clone()
  while (iteratedDate.month() === month - 1) {
    currentMonth.push(iteratedDate.format("L"))
    iteratedDate.add(1, "day")
  }
  ```
- get dates for final of previous month: start loop with the start of current month, push date and stop when iterated date is Sunday

  ```js
  iteratedDate = startOfMonth.clone()
  while (iteratedDate.day() !== 0) {
    iteratedDate.subtract(1, "day")
    finalsOfPrevMonth.push(iteratedDate.format("L"))
  }
  ```
- get dates for start of next month: start loop with end of current month, push incremented date till the total dates reach length of 42

  ```js
  iteratedDate = endOfMonth.clone()
  while (finalsOfPrevMonth.length + currentMonth.length + startsOfNextMonth.length < 42) {
    iteratedDate.add(1, "day")
    startsOfNextMonth.push(iteratedDate.format("L"))
  }
  ```

---

#### Implementation

```js
const getDates = (month, year) => {
  const startOfMonth = moment()
    .month(month - 1)
    .year(year)
    .startOf("month")
  const endOfMonth = moment()
    .month(month - 1)
    .year(year)
    .endOf("month")

  const finalsOfPrevMonth = []
  const currentMonth = []
  const startsOfNextMonth = []
  let iteratedDate = null

  iteratedDate = startOfMonth.clone()
  while (iteratedDate.day() !== 0) {
    iteratedDate.subtract(1, "day")
    finalsOfPrevMonth.push(iteratedDate.format("L"))
  }

  iteratedDate = startOfMonth.clone()
  while (iteratedDate.month() === month - 1) {
    currentMonth.push(iteratedDate.format("L"))
    iteratedDate.add(1, "day")
  }

  iteratedDate = endOfMonth.clone()
  while (finalsOfPrevMonth.length + currentMonth.length + startsOfNextMonth.length < 42) {
    iteratedDate.add(1, "day")
    startsOfNextMonth.push(iteratedDate.format("L"))
  }

  return [...finalsOfPrevMonth.reverse(), ...currentMonth, ...startsOfNextMonth]
}

console.log("March 2020")
console.log(getDates(3, 2020))
console.log("April 2020")
console.log(getDates(4, 2020))
console.log("May 2020")
console.log(getDates(5, 2020))
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

---

#### Assertion

[image: March 2020]

[image: April 2020]